# Generate form symfony2 with others entities and QueryBuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm wondering how I can generate a form asking the user which country he's living in.

Currently here is my code in my AnnonceType.php (form)

```
$builder
->add('idPa', 'entity', array( 
            'label' => 'Pays',
            'class' => 'nftAnnonceBundle:Pays',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
            {    
                return                
                $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('nomPa')
                ->from('nftAnnonceBundle:Pays', 'p');                    
            },
            'property' => 'nom_pa'
         ))
```

I'm looking for custom query because i have a geom data column in my database and my application is crashing if doctrine does load it ...

To be clear i'd just like to create a select fields asking the label_country (from my database) to the user and having as value the id_country.
I tried to overwrite the select fields from createQueryBuilder() with a -> select but doens't seems to work.

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 72 near 'p': Error: 'p' is already defined.
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: shouldn't your query builder be `$er->createQueryBuilder()->select('p.nomPa')->from('nftAnnonceBundle:Pays', 'p');`

Comment: If I don't put an alias as parameter for createQueryBuilder function, symfony returns me an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is this error message because when you do

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('p')
```

It already creates implicitly the `->from('nftAnnonceBundle:Pays', 'p');`
Moreover, you must not select the displayed label in the QueryBuilder, but rather in `choice_label` attribute or in the entity `__toString` method.

So you can just do

```
$builder
    ->add('idPa', 'entity', array( 
        'label' => 'Pays',
        'class' => 'nftAnnonceBundle:Pays',
        'choice_label' => 'nomPa'
     ))
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

[EDITED following comments]
If you want to restrict fields loaded by the EntityType form field for performance purpose, you can use a `QueryBuilder` with [doctrine partials objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html). In this case it can be something like :

```
$builder
    ->add('idPa', 'entity', array( 
        'label' => 'Pays',
        'class' => 'nftAnnonceBundle:Pays',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {    
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('partial p.{id,nomPa}')                   
        },
        'property' => 'nom_pa'
     ))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply ! But when I run this code (I already did to be honest) doctrine is querying a whole object whose contain geometry value which make my application crash because of the big amount of data loading ... I'd just like doctrine to select my "label_pays" instead of the whole object including "geom_pays", any idea ?

Comment: Ok maybe you can try [partials objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html) and use it in the `queryBuilder`. Something like this : `return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('partial p.{id,nomPa}')`